# Vertical bargraph with different vertical starting & ending points

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that plots vertical bars that runs from start to end. Each bar has a different starting and ending points and all points are negative. I try using plt.bar, but so far without real success.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x  = 1
y  = [-97, -27]

plt.subplot(111, frameon=False)
plt.ylim(-280, 1)
plt.bar(x+0.0, y,  width=0.1)
```

However this creates a bar that runs from -97 to 0 instead of -97 to -27. How do I plot this in a nice way?

Plt.bar() plots first a bar from 0 to -97 and then from 0 to -27. I could plot the second bar in the background color but I find this an ugly solution. Does someone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

An example of what I want:
[image: An example of what I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to play with the `bottom` argument of the [`bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar) plotting function.

By default, the bars are grounded to 0.
In the following example, I define some bars with its two ends. Matplotlib requires the bottom point and the height.
Hence I compute them with list comprehension:

- `[abs(b[0] - b[1]) for b in bars]` returns the height of each bar;
- `[min(b) for b in bars]` gives the bottom of each bar.

You can then play with colors too, etc.

It's up to you to decide how you store your bars coordinates.
Either stick to your current format, with both ends.
Else you can change to better suit your Matplotlib usage, storing them as `(bottom, height)`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():

    bars = [(-97, -27), (-50, -10), (-2, -15)]

    plt.subplot(111, frameon=False)
    plt.xlim(-1, len(bars))
    plt.ylim(-100, 1)

    plt.bar(range(len(bars)),
            [abs(b[0] - b[1]) for b in bars],
            bottom=[min(b) for b in bars],
            width=0.1)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want that Matplotlib automatically handle different bar colors, call multiple times the `bar` function on the same axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():

    bars = [(-1, -14), (-3, -20), (-2, -23), (-2, -26)]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(5, 10))
    plt.xlim(0, len(bars)+4)
    plt.ylim(-28, 1)
    plt.xticks([])

    for i, bar in enumerate(bars):
        ax.bar(i+3,
               abs(bar[0] - bar[1]),
               bottom=min(bar),
               width=0.9)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]